# testing a method with should_receive using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have address method which instantiates a new class and returns some information.

```
class Office  
  attribute :id
  def address
    info = Services::Employee.new
    info.contact = [contact]
    info.id = id

    info
  end
end
```

Now in the above address method contact(one inside an array) is another method which returns a bunch of things.

Now in my rspec test I just want to say the info.contact returns [contact] without actually testing it with data.
I read about should_receive but i am not sure how to test the above method using should_receive.

Here is what I tried:

```
info = Employee.deserialize(JSON.parse(info.to_json))
it 'returns info' do
  Employee.should_receive(:info.contact).and_return('[contact]')
  expect(helper.address).to eq(info)
end
```

I got this error:

```
   expected: 1 time with any arguments
   received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `info` is an instance of `Employee` within your test. Therefore it is `Employee` which receives the message `contact`.

Try changing  your test such that the `should_receive` is placed on `Employee` directly:

```
Employee.any_instance.should_receive(:contact).and_return('[contact]')
```

Comment: `contact` is being called as an instance method, but you're proposing setting an expectation on a class method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Services::Employee,.any_instance.should_receive(:contact=) {|value|
  value.should eq <expected_value>
  <expected_value>
}
```